# Extending local Storage Repository in XenServer 6.0

Tags: raid, hard-drive, partition, xenserver, expansion

My server has 2x 3-disk RAID 5 arrays. This weekend I plan on deleting the second array and adding the HDDs to the first array.

However how would I go about extending the partition in XenServer 6.0 so that the entire array is in use, without losing the data that was already on the first array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by reading this article : http://scotgate.org/2006/07/03/growing-a-raid5-array-mdadm/

I suggest you degrade the array that you want to destroy. Add the disk that you freed up to the first array. That should give you enough space to move over all your virtual disk images. Once the sr is empty destroy it, and the raid, and add the remaining 2 disks. This leaves u with a final of 6 disks in ur epic raid 5 array. If you are having trouble with space u might consider an ext3 type SR which provides "thin provisioning" and will give u some breathing room